# i586-poky-linux-g++: no such file or directory Error compiling for board Intel® Edison

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors, edison

I'm facing this compilation issue.

Arduino: 1.8.4 (Linux), Board: "Intel® Edison"

`fork/exec /home/jimish/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/core2-32-poky-linux/1.6.2+1.0/i686/sysroots/pokysdk/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux/i586-poky-linux-g++: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board Intel® Edison.`

**Arduino IDE:**
[image: Arduino IDE]

---

**Web IDE:**
[image: Web IDE]

Comment: please remove the two pictures and include the actual output text, so that text searches can be made. .... use the `edit` button

Comment: I've already pasted error there. The pictures are proof, that it's not a fault of my local machine or local ide. @jsotola

Comment: @JimishFotariya - Have you tried to access this file from the command line?  Usually its just a path issue.

Comment: @code-gorilla No i haven't tried that. But web-editor compiles on their server so I think it is a bug in original source.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to pursue with the creators of this non-Arduino toolchain.   Either you have a broken install (does the file even exist?) or (if it is there but won't run) an issue like a 32 bit executable that won't run on a 64 bit system unless you install the optional 32-bit system libraries package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Intel, in their infinite wisdom* have lots of hard-coded paths to libraries in the binaries (why, heaven only knows) and then a set of scripts that munge those binaries to sort out where the libraries really are.

That script uses an option to `find` that was deprecated 13 years ago.

Way to keep up with the times, Intel...

So you need to make some fixes to get the toolchain to install properly.

I have created "fix" scripts for both the Edison and the Galileo that you can use to replace your broken toolchain.

- https://github.com/majenkotech/IntelFixes

---

*i.e., sheer incompetence